# Trying to suggest someone to a friend on Facebook and getting the "The server found your request confusing and isn't sure how to proceed." error

Tags: facebook

I am trying to suggest friend X to friend Y on Facebook and I get the "The server found your request confusing and isn't sure how to proceed." error:

[image]

What are some likely cause for the issue and is there any way around?

Note that suggested friends does work well for all 5 other friends I have tried suggesting friends to (before and after getting this error message).

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, it seems like the error in this case was triggered by another action (sharing page / public event) though :/

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, apparently no solution has been found so far :(

Comment: @pnuts I don't think so in this case: both users have signed up years ago.

Comment: Perhaps try clearing your browser's cache, or trying it in a different browser?